# Processing two Multidimensional Arrays and skipping arrays that share a value in the final output

Tags: php, arrays, loops, recursion, foreach

I am working with two (2) Arrays dynamically created from MySQL data. One array contains all tables available for booking. A second table holds information about tables booked for specified times. Things look like below:

```
 <?php

    $all_tables = array(
                     0 => array('table_no' => '102', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'red', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'legal'),
                     1 => array('table_no' => '123', 'size' => '220sqm', 'color' => 'grey', 'shape' => 'square', 'dept' => 'Sales'),
                     2 => array('table_no' => '133', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'black', 'shape' => 'square', 'dept' => 'Accounts'),
                     3 => array('table_no' => '168', 'size' => '280sqm', 'color' => 'blue', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'legal'),
                     4 => array('table_no' => '714', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'black', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'Marketing')
                   );
 $booked_tables = array(
                     0 => array('booking_no' => '1', 'table_no' => '123', 'date_booked' => '01-05-18'),
                     1 => array('booking_no' => '2', 'table_no' => '168', 'date_booked' => '03-05-18')
                   );
        ?>
```

### What I want to do:

The main array is the $all_tables Array. I want to eliminate all arrays from the $all_tables array whose table_no matches the table number of an array in the $booked_array table. In the above example, the resultant arrays after processing these array would be:

```
$available_tables = array(
                     0 => array('table_no' => '102', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'red', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'legal'),
                     1 => array('table_no' => '133', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'black', 'shape' => 'square', 'dept' => 'Accounts'),
                     2 => array('table_no' => '714', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'black', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'Marketing')
                   );
```

If possible, I would be happy being able to create a multidimensional array containing the removed arrays. But itis fine if they are removed.

What I haved Tried:

```
foreach($all_rooms as $rooms) {
    foreach($booked_rooms as $booked) {
        $booked['table_no'];
    }

 if (( $booked['table_no']) == ($rooms['table_no'])) {
   //remove some array or identify some array
 } 

}
```

Sadly, I could not move past the not-so-good start. I am thinking two loops could do the trick. Or maybe it requires a custom function or neither. Anyway, my brain cells aren't able to work out the logic.

Question:

How do I achieve the stated desired result above? Any suggestions, hints? Is this even possible? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A clean way without `foreach`

```
<?php

$all_tables = array(
    0 => array('table_no' => '102', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'red', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'legal'),
    1 => array('table_no' => '123', 'size' => '220sqm', 'color' => 'grey', 'shape' => 'square', 'dept' => 'Sales'),
    2 => array('table_no' => '133', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'black', 'shape' => 'square', 'dept' => 'Accounts'),
    3 => array('table_no' => '168', 'size' => '280sqm', 'color' => 'blue', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'legal'),
    4 => array('table_no' => '714', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'black', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'Marketing')
);
$booked_tables = array(
    0 => array('booking_no' => '1', 'table_no' => '123', 'date_booked' => '01-05-18'),
    1 => array('booking_no' => '2', 'table_no' => '168', 'date_booked' => '03-05-18')
);

//extract all numbers in an array like ['123', '168', ...]
$booked_tables_numbers = array_column($booked_tables, 'table_no');

//remove if booked
$available_tables= array_filter($all_tables, function($array) use($booked_tables_numbers) {
    return !in_array($array['table_no'], $booked_tables_numbers);
});
```

Comment: Wow, this really is more than clean.  It is also much easier to understand. Those Lopps were strangling me. Not only did this solve the problem but also enabled me to solve other problems related to multidimensional arrays. I plugged it into the actual data from MySQL and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest taking it a step farther back. If you modify the way you fetch the results from your query, you can make this comparison (and possibly other things as well) a bit easier to handle.

Try using `table_no` as a key when you fetch the rows from your query. Something like this:

```
while ($table = $table_query->fetch()) {
    $all_tables[$table['table_no']] = $table;
}

while ($booking = $bookings_query->fetch()) {
    $booked_tables[$booking['table_no']][] = $booking;
}
```

This way, the `$all_tables` array will be indexed by `table_no`.

```
$all_tables = array(
    102 => array('table_no' => '102', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'red', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'legal'),
    123 => array('table_no' => '123', 'size' => '220sqm', 'color' => 'grey', 'shape' => 'square', 'dept' => 'Sales'),
    133 => array('table_no' => '133', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'black', 'shape' => 'square', 'dept' => 'Accounts'),
    168 => array('table_no' => '168', 'size' => '280sqm', 'color' => 'blue', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'legal'),
    714 => array('table_no' => '714', 'size' => '200sqm', 'color' => 'black', 'shape' => 'round', 'dept' => 'Marketing')
);
```

And the `$booked_tables` will be an array of sets of bookings associated with each `table_no`.

```
$booked_tables = array(
    123 => [array('booking_no' => '1', 'table_no' => '123', 'date_booked' => '01-05-18')],
    168 => [array('booking_no' => '2', 'table_no' => '168', 'date_booked' => '03-05-18')]
);
```

I suggested this structure because I'm assuming that `table_no` is unique in `$all_tables`, but not necessarily in `$booked_tables`.

This way, to get available tables, you can just use `array_diff_key`.

```
$available_tables = array_diff_key($all_tables, $booked_tables);
```

Or for the remaining set, `array_intersect_key`.

```
$not_available_tables = array_intersect_key($all_tables, $booked_tables);
```

Comment: A user selects a period during which they want to book a Table.  No table is selected at that point, so no Table_no. One query is for all tables and another is for booked tables. The idea is to find all tables that are booked for the period a user wants to book a table while returning all Tables from another MySQL Table. That why I wanted a way to remove those tables appearing on the Booked Tables array from the all tables array. The MySQL 'booked table' is updated manually by the Table Owners, once a table has been booked. Your suggestion is great, I just need to rework my the logic.